# garbage collection in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider this custom queue implementation (as shown in pic):
once the head has been popped, the `next` element becomes the head.

There is no one referring to this popped element *but we see that it has a property `next` which refers to an active and reachable `head`*.

Would it be **garbage collected** on its own, or should I explicitly set the `next` of the popped object to `null` ?

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether it itself refers to other, active variables or not, as long as no active variable/object refers to it. But I'd be curious to see an experiment to validate that.

Comment: Locally I was NOT able to see a difference (in my machine) but on a server machine I see the difference.  Now I am interested to know if there is a guarantee from the server for garbage collection in these cases?